# Android/Java asyncTask wait

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I can't find a solution on here so I am going to ask it. I am building an Android(5.0) app. It is going to be a dutch news reader, but i am stuck on the part where it is retrieving the news items. In the center of te code, the list results gets filled with the items. It shows the results in the Log, but the task says it ended before the list got filled. Anyone? Been stuck on this for 4 hours. It should wait until the "service.GetNewsItems(cb);" is finished.

Code:

```
    public class GetNewsAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        public List<Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>();
        private RestAdapter restAdapter;
        public RootObject rootObject = new RootObject();
        public MainActivity ma;
        static final String API_URL = SECRETAPILINK

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                OkHttpClient mOkHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
                mOkHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                mOkHttpClient.setReadTimeout(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(API_URL).setClient(new OkClient(mOkHttpClient)).setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL) .build();
                GetNewsService service = restAdapter.create(GetNewsService.class);

                Callback<RootObject> cb = new Callback<RootObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(RootObject responseObject, Response response) {
                        results.addAll(responseObject.results);
                        for (int i = 0; i< results.size();i++){
                            Log.v("AASSAA", "DSFSDFHE");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                        Log.v("AASSAA", error.toString());
                    }
                };
                service.GetNewsItems(cb);
                Log.v("AASSAASIZER", String.valueOf(results.size()));
                return "Done";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            }
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {

            }
            public List<Result> GetList(){
                return results;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is service.GetNewsItems(cb); async?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a AsyncTask, and inside the AsyncTask, you're creating ANOTHER thread (Retrofit does this).

This is why your code is screwed up.
`service.GetNewsItems(cb)` is async, so when you return from your AsyncTask, the Retrofit call is not done yet, and therefore your data is not ready yet.

You should either use Retrofit alone, or AsyncTask alone. Never mix them. There are a million guides to Retrofit (both version 1.9 and 2.0-beta) on the internet, so just google it.